# MatLab OOP Setting a Property via a Utility Method

Tags: matlab, oop

I'm trying to change a property in a class called `houses` via a utility method which is `Static`.  I'm getting terribly confused with the reference `obj` as I don't know when and where it should be used.  I am trying to bypass the constructor method so I can access the `setProperty` method, but I am getting errors such as `too many output arguments`.  I've tried passing in `obj` as well as `x`, but I get similar errors.  However, I can change the property `a` if I pass in a value to the constructor method.

```
classdef houses

properties
    a;
end

methods

    % constructor method
    function obj = houses()
    end
end

methods (Static)

    function setProperty(x)
        obj.a = x;
    end

end

end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, you should not use static methods to set properties of a class. If your property is public, then you can use a static method *but it is highly recommended that you do not*. If your property is private/protected, then you definitely cannot use a static method to modify it.

Your class should look like this then (I took the liberty of stating explicitly the access properties of each block):

```
classdef houses

    properties (Access = private)
        a;
    end

   methods (Access = public)

       % constructor method
       function obj = houses()
       end

       function SetA(obj, a)
          obj.a = a;
       end

       function DoSomething(obj, more_parameters)
           % Lengthy stuff here
       end

   end

end
```

Now, regarding your question about `obj`: the answer is you must pass `obj` as the first argument of *every instance method*. The variable `obj` refers to the current instance of the class in a generic way. See for example the method `DoSomething`.

Static methods do not have access to any of the properties of the class, unless public. As such, when declaring a static method, you should not pass the `obj` variable.

Last thing: *always* use explicit access modifiers for your properties and methods. It will save you some headaches.

Comment: Thanks guys, I have just copied and pasted the code above (changed the properties access to public) and typed `a = houses` then `a.SetA(10)` then `a` then return and the command line echoes `a: []`.  Also, within the `SetA` function, I'm getting a red line under `obj.a` which is stating at least 3 possible errors.  In regards to the variable `obj` that needs to be passed into every instance method, is this the same as "This" or "self"?

Comment: @user1574598 yes, the variable `obj` is the same as `this` in other languages. To fix the errors that you are seeing, check the difference between handle and value classes [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/comparing-handle-and-value-classes.html)

Comment: Ah, I think I'm getting there a little.  So the reason the method `SetA` was not changing the property `a` was because when `obj.a = a` was called, it was making another copy of `a`?  Therefore not changing the property `a` and making it appear as `a:[]`?  So in order to get around this you need to return the modified object `a`?  Also, is the `handle` like passing by reference like a C pointer?

Comment: By "always use explicit access modifiers for your properties and methods", what do you mean? do you mean to always write getters and setters? what did you mean about method?

Comment: @user1574598 Yes. Yes. Yes. Yes :) Handle sub-classes behave like pointers; nevertheless, handles are much safer than pointers :)

Comment: @seb if you take a look at the class he posted in the question, the `properties` statement has no access modifier. In the class I posted you can see that the `properties` and `methods` statement has the `Access = public` modifier. This makes their access explicit and not implicit (by default if you do not specify the modifier, the properties are public, the same for the methods). Making the acces expicit is much better for you (you will avoid weird bugs) and for the people reading your code. When coding, always state explicitly your intentions :)

Comment: Ha OK. I agree, especially since C++ has the opposite default (private for class members) so it's clearer to be explicit.

Answer (score 1):

A static method is not typically supposed to access an object (hence it does not have access to `obj`).
If you want to modify a static propperty (shared by all objects, and the class itself), you can use something like:

```
classdef houses
    properties (Static)
        a;
    end
    methods
        % constructor method
        function obj = houses()
        end
    end
    methods (Static)
        function setProperty(x)
            houses.a = x;
        end
    end
end
```

Regarding `obj`, it is the 1st argument of every methods (non static). So when you do:

```
o = myClass();
o.myMethod(args);
```

Matlab will see this as:

```
myMethod(o, args);
```

So when you define the method, you have to put `obj` as the 1st argument (in fact you can choose any name, it does not have to be `obj`).

Comment: Thanks for the help also, I notice you have the properties set to `Static`.  What does it mean in the context of MatLab?

Comment: The property is common to all objects and the class (so there is only 1 instance in memory, and they all reference the same memory location). If one object modifies it, it is modified for all objects. And you don't need to create an object to modify it: you can access this value with `yourClass.staticProp` even before any object is created (or if you have objects created `anyObject.staticProp` works also).